# Python geocoder limit

Tags: python, google-maps, for-loop, google-geocoder

I have data of post number in excel. I input in python as a list.
I use geocoder library to get the latitude and longitude by the post number so i can put on map later on.

```
g = geocoder.google('1700002')
g.latlng
```

g.latlng brings me a list with [latitude,longitude] in it.
Since is take string only. I changed the values from float to int to get rid of point 0 (133.0 = 130). then make it to string to read it.

```
yubin_frame = yubin['yubin'] #post data
#1st put it to ing to get rid of float
yubin_list_int = map(int, yubin_list)
#then make it to string to in put all to string
yubin_list_str = map(str, yubin_list_int)
```

I made this for-loop to make list of both latitude and longitude like this.

```
#create a new list that include all data in Yubin_zahyou list
Yubin_zahyou = []
for i in range(len(yubin_list_str)):
    Yubin_zahyou.append(geocoder.google(yubin_list_str[i]).latlng)
```

My problem is that i have nearly 30000 data and geocoder brings only nearly 2500 input!. Does this mean geocoder has a limit or I made a mistake somehow?

Comment: [Google Maps Geocoding API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has rate limit as written here in Providers.
https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits
as for google it nearly only gives 2500 limit per day.